# Adjust exception message basing on missing information

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, command-line-arguments

Having such code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser.add_argument("--u_shape_dict", default="", action='store',
                    help="required for ...")

    parser.add_argument("--v_shape_dict", default="", action='store',
                    help="required for ...")

    u_shape_dict = args['u_shape_dict']
    if not u_shape_dict:
        raise Exception('u_shape_dict is missing. Please provide it')

    v_shape_dict = args['v_shape_dict']
    if not v_shape_dict:
        raise Exception('v_shape_dict is missing. Please provide it')
```

I want to combine this two exceptions into one like this:

```
if not u_shape_dict or v_shape_dict:
    raise Exception('%s is missing. Please provide it' % )
```

Is it possible to do so? 
What actually I need to put after `%` sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [required](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html#required) option, argparse will take care of the error reporting